# How to log google search results in console using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have tried a couple of approaches, I've been successfully able to launch the browser and search the term. I've tried using for loop but i think I'm missing something.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows how you're doing the search, and how you're trying to log the results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are exactly looking for, but to log things from your google search results, you can do this:

```
${result}= Get text     xpath=//*[@id="search"]
Log to console  ${result}
```

Now you can refine this logger with providing an exact xpath of the element/link/text that you want to log with Robot Framework.